# .htaccess block sub domain root but still have access from another domain in a different directory

Tags: .htaccess

I hope someone could advise this is a probably is a easy question but my knowledge of .htaccess is limited.

I have inherited a odd file structure that has dependancies on files from a previous install.

Below is a spseudo file structure which mirrors what I have on a sub-domain.

```
+site-directory
    index.html
    file.php
    another-file.php
   + other-folder
    display.php
```

The sub domain site directory is:

```
/site-directory
```

I want to access the sub domain from the main domain from the following url:

```
/site-directory/other-folder/display.php
```

the problem I am having is if you put www.subdomainurl.com in the browser the previous install is displayed.

How can I stop this and only access the sub doamin via

```
 /site-directory/other-folder/display.php
```

I have blocked indexing from robots.txt

What would be best practices for this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi hope someone can help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very clear to me, so my answer is based on some assumptions.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomainurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /other-folder/display.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I also deleted (after testing!) files that could be removed just to make sure they dont get indexed!